# Using a directive as the md-dialog

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to include the code for a dialog inside a directive. In other words:

```
$mdDialog.show({ ..... template: '<my-directive></my-directive>', ..... })
```

and, of course, "my directive" would be

```
<md-dialog>.....</md-dialog>
```

The only solution is to have the full skeleton of the dialog outside "my-directive" and directly imported in `$mdDialog.show()`. FYI, I tried `transclude=true` but it's not working either.

In case you are wondering the reason for this mess, I'm trying to avoid controllers. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Credit: much of the text was from someone called lrondanini on https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I got this to work was by adding a `<md-dialog>` tag around my directive on dialog template options.

```
$mdDialog.show({ ..., template: '<md-dialog><my-directive></my-directive></md-dialog>' });
```

The dialog service tries to access a md-dialog element to configure the ARIA tags before it compiles the template. 
That's where the code fails to work.